# Using NSTemporaryDirectory without increasing tmp folder size

Tags: ios, xcode

In my app the user has the possibility to upload and download 700*700mb images. These images are downloaded and displayed in a few UIImageViews.
My app itself is quite small, but the Documents & Data folder is enormous e.g. 17gb and it keeps increasing exponentially. My app runs on both ipad and on iPhone. Will the docs & data folder in my ipad is 6mb, on my ipod it is 17gb. I have downloaded the app package, and found out that the tmp folder is huge. there are some Stack-log files 1gb big. I found out the problem was related to the NSTemporarydirectory.

I save an image in this way:

```
NSString *title = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"Folder3"];
PhotoiPhoneViewController* sharedSingleton = [PhotoiPhoneViewController sharedManager];

NSString *destDir = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"Folder2"];
NSString *filename3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@sizefile.pages.%@", destDir, title, sharedSingleton.tagString];

NSString *SizePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@sizefile.pages.%@", title, sharedSingleton.tagString]];

[self.restClient loadFile:filename3 intoPath:SizePath];
```

Is this the right way to do it, or should I use:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *CommentPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@commentfile.txt.%ld", title, (long)sharedSingleton.tagNumber]]
```

Since I want the files to be deleted after use, I thought that the NStemporaryDirectory would be deleted as soon as the file was used. What should I do??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look into using [NSURLCache](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html) as these manage the purging.
See also [NSHipster/NSURLCache](http://nshipster.com/nsurlcache/)

Or you could use a library like [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) which will handle a cache size as well

Edit: In answer to your question
The operating system used to leave files in the temporary directory, however, since iOS 5.0 it will purge files from this directory if it sees the need. See [this link](http://www.marco.org/2011/10/13/ios5-caches-cleaning) for more information

Comment: Thanks for the answer, all'have a look at the links, but this doesn't really answer my question. Is it right to use the NStemporaryDoc. directory?

Comment: The tmp of my ipad has some images, while the tmp of my ipod has many logs, why is this? they both run ios6